# How do I push a scala.xml.Null into a Stack[MetaData]?

Tags: xml, scala

I want to maintain a stack of element attributes in a `collection.immutable.Stack[xml.MetaData]`. The problem is the following:

```
scala> import scala.xml.MetaData
import scala.xml.MetaData

scala> import scala.xml.Null
import scala.xml.Null

scala> val s = Stack[MetaData]()
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stack[scala.xml.MetaData] = Stack()

scala> s push Null
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Stack[scala.xml.MetaData] = Stack()

scala> s.pop
java.util.NoSuchElementException: pop of empty stack
  at scala.collection.immutable.Stack.pop(Stack.scala:113)
  ... 33 elided
```

the stack is empty! I suppose this happens because `MetaData` is actually an iterator, and `Null` represents an empty iterator.

I want to be able to pop as many times as I pushed, but I can't because I won't have pushed anything every time `MetaData` is `Null`. What's a suggested workaround for this? I could wrap it in an `Option`, but that would just be weird because that would always be `Some`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is not about xml.MetaData or somehing like that.
Problem is that you are using a immutable data structure but trying to change it's content. Immutable Stack's push doesn't mutate the current stack it just returns a stack with new value pushed. You should use `scala.collection.mutable.Stack` for mutable things. following works:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack
val s = Stack[MetaData]()
s push Null
s.pop
```

with following output:

```
res9: scala.xml.MetaData =
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. I actually did pay attention to the immutability and I used the updated stack in my code, but not in the REPL test that I pasted. Additionally, my problem was that I was interpreting the console output of the stack as if the top was on the right side (end of the underlying collection), when the top is actually on the left side (head of the underlying collection).